# how to pass an argument to a python script when starting with nohup

Tags: python, bash, nohup

I need to start a python script with bash using nohup passing an arg that aids in defining a constant in a script I import.  There are lots of questions about passing args but I haven't found a successful way using nohup.

a simplified version of my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BUCKET=$1
echo $BUCKET
script='/home/path/to/script/script.py'
echo "starting $script with nohup"
nohup /usr/bin/python $script $BUCKET &
```

the relevant part of my config script i'm importing:

```
FLAG = sys.argv[0]
if FLAG == "b1": 
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "key"
    BUCKET = "bucket1" 
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret"
elif FLAG == "b2": 
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "key"
    BUCKET = "bucket2"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret"
else:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "key"
    BUCKET = "bucket3"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "secret"
```

the script thats using it:

```
from config import BUCKET, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

#do stuff with the values.
```

Frankly, since I'm passing the args to script.py, I'm not confident that they'll be in scope for the import script.  That said, when I take a similar approach without using nohup, it works.

Comment: I find it strange that this would ever work. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name, not the first argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the argument vector for any program starts with the program itself, and then all of its arguments and options. Depending on the language, the program may be `sys.argv[0]`, `argv[0]`, `$0`, or something else, but it's basically always argument #0.

Each program whose job is to run another program—like `nohup`, and like the Python interpreter itself—generally drops itself and all of its own options, and gives the target program the rest of the command line.

So, [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) takes a `COMMAND` and zero or more `ARGS`. Inside that `COMMAND`, `argv[0]` will be `COMMAND` itself (in this case, `'/usr/bin/python'`), and `argv[1]` and later will be the additional arguments (`'/home/path/to/script/script.py'` and whatever `$BUCKET` resolves to).

Next, Python takes zero or more options, a script, and zero or more args to that script, and exposes the script and its args as [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv). So, in your script, `sys.argv[0]` will be `'/home/path/to/script/script.py'`, and `sys.argv[1]` will be whatever `$BUCKET` resolves to.

And `bash` works similarly to Python; `$1` will be the first argument to the bash wrapper script (`$0` will be the script itself), and so on. So, `sys.argv[1]` in the inner Python script will end up getting the first argument passed to the bash wrapper script.

Importing doesn't affect `sys.argv` at all. So, in both your `config` module and your top-level script, if you `import sys`, `sys.argv[1]` will hold the `$1` passed to the bash wrapper script.

(On some platforms, in some circumstances `argv[0]` may not have the complete path, or may even be empty. But that isn't relevant here. What you care about is the eventual `sys.argv[1]`, and `bash`, `nohup`, and `python` are all guaranteed to pass that through untouched.)

Comment: very clear answer.  thank you.  my mistake is basically not understanding that the script is the first arg.

Comment: @Brad: Ah, maybe I can explain that better.

Comment: man.  wish i could upvote more than once. thank you. incredibly helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
nohup python3 -u ./train.py --dataset dataset_directory/ --model model_output_directory > output.log &
```

Here Im executing train.py file with python3, Then -u is used to ignore buffering and show the logs on the go without storing, specifying my **dataset_directory** with argument style and **model_output_directory** then **Greater than symbol(>)**

then the logs is stored in **output.log** and them atlast and(**&**) symbol is used

To terminate this process

```
ps ax | grep train
```

then note the process_ID

```
sudo kill -9 Process_ID
```